# React props validation only fired once for each Element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I couldn't find the details about how/when React props validation works besides the [Reusable Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation) doc. From my experiment, it looks like the props validation will only be fired once per Element (If I understand it correctly, an Element is an object representing a DOM node, like the JSX code we would write in the `render()` function), no matter how many times the Component is initialized and rendered. An example (and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnunus7w/1/)),

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('component-1')
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('component-2')
);
```

I can find a [maybe related PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/2920), but I wonder if there is more detailed information about how that works and when the error is fired.

A real use case that I want it to be fired every time a Component is initialized is that in tests we may need to check again it in multiple test cases, and I have no idea how the get around it. Any advice would be very appreciated. Thanks!